# How to bind a key to custom tabstop in vimrc file?

Tags: vim

I have the following in my .vimrc file:

```
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
```

I want to bind a key (for example, Ctrl-Tab) to change the above values from 4 to 2. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using a ternary conditional based on the current value of `tabstop`.

Here's an example binding it to Leader+t in normal mode:

```
nnoremap <leader>t :exec &tabstop == 2 ? "set tabstop=4" : "set tabstop=2"<CR>
```

Do note that you can't bind things to bind to Ctrl+Tab in the terminal, as `Tab` is already a control key. You can however, in gVim.

Answer (score 2):

> What's the best way to do this?

```
nnoremap <silent><C-Tab> :let &ts = (&ts == 4) ? 2 : 4<CR>
```

Still to be noted that mapping `C-Tab` only works under GUI.